# Create Resources on Specific Context

Tags: qt, opengl, openglcontext

I have a Qt OpenGL application that uses a `QOpenGLWidget` to render content. In another class (let's call it `Resources`), I want to create OpenGL resources like VBOs, VAO, shader programs, etc. for this widget. This creation method is not called by the `QOpenGLWidget`, but by an external caller.

For some reason, there exist two OpenGL contexts in my application (one is probably used for GUI stuff and the other for the `QOpenGLWidget`). Hence, when the resource creation method is called, I cannot be sure that the correct context is active. So when I call

```
QOpenGLVertexArrayObject vao;
vao.create();
```

in the Resources class, I cannot be sure that this VAO is created on the right context. The Resources class does not have access to the widget. Thus, `context.makeCurrent()` cannot be called (because I do not know the surface).

Is there a direct way to specify the context, on which the resources should be created? Storing the surface in the Resources file (along with the context) seems very untidy.

Comment: Can't this external caller call `yourOpenGLWidget->makeCurrent()` before initializing the GL resources?

Comment: @peppe No, the caller doesn't know the widget. He doesn't even know OpenGL exists. The call is basically "load some data". And this very Resources implementation also creates OpenGL resources. Others do not.

Comment: Hm, why don't you just return a vector of the data and let some other object with access to the correct context build the VBO and VAO?

Comment: @xsquared The Resources class does have access to the context. But the context alone does not help here because the associated surface is missing. Yes, I could also pass the surface, but I would rather avoid that. I have an IOC-based workaround implemented right now, but I would like to see if there is a direct way of using a specific context.

Comment: Ah sorry. Replace “context” with “surface” in my previous comment. I don’t know your concrete structure, but building the openGL objects later doesn’t sound like a bad solution to me… Especially because as far as I know OpenGL invocations should only bother about the existence of a context instead of who owns it. So explicitly specifying it here sounds more like a hack to me — regardless of the question if that’s even possible.

Comment: Or as an alternative your external caller could emit a signal before calling the Resources class. Since [code after a signal waits until all slots have returrned](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), the surface could make its context current before Resources starts to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way to create resources on a specific context. I worked around this issue with the following structure:

I created an interface `OpenGLContextProvider`, which is very simple:

```
class OpenGLContextProvider
{
public:
    virtual void MakeOpenGLContextCurrent() = 0;
};
```

The OpenGL widget implements this interface:

```
class GLView : public QOpenGLWidget, public OpenGLContextProvider
{
    //...
};
void GLView::MakeOpenGLContextCurrent()
{
    makeCurrent();
}
```

As such, the `OpenGLContextProvider` (i.e. the OpenGL widget) is injected into the Resource object's constructor. Before it needs the context, it calls the according method:

```
void Resources::LoadSomeData()
{
    //Load data...

    //Create OpenGL resources
    ctx->MakeOpenGLContextCurrent(); //ctx is of type OpenGLContextProvider*
    vao.create(); //is now on the correct context
    //etc.
}
```